# Prefabs does not update if you duplicate a prefab and then modify it

Tags: unity-game-engine

This may not be an issue, but it sorta defy the purpose of having prefabs.

I have a prefab; then for various reasons, I did modify it. What I usually do is to drag the prefab in the scene, modify it and click the apply button to save the changes.

I did duplicate few times this prefab, modified one and did press apply button. Then I realized that all the other duplicates did not update accordingly.

Even the prefab itself, didn't update at all; I had to drag and drop the modified prefab on top of the original prefab icon to get that changed.

I do remember that in the past; each prefab would propagate changes, every time you modify one; and also, I recall that every time that you modify a prefab, you would get the warning, telling you that you are breaking the prefab. Which didn't even happen.

Did the prefab behavior changed recently? I didn't touch Unity since V3.0, so I may have missed some change in the editor, now that I am using 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

I did 2 tests. The first one was:

- I instantiated a prefab
- Changed an attribute
- Applied

My first result was the propragation working fine.

My second one was:

- I instantiated a prefab
- Added an child GameObject
- Applied

This one still propragated.

So is working fine on version 5.3.4f

Comment: Did you duplicate the prefab, made a modification on one prefab, apply and then verify that all the instances of that prefab were modified? In my case it does not happen. If I change the box collider size, and apply, all the other prefabs won't propagate the change, but still display the previous box size. If I drag the prefab from the assets into the scene, then the changes will be displayed. So the issue is only when you have duplicates, from what I can tell.

Comment: No, I modified the duplicated instance and after I applied.